# Spring-boot configuration only package

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to create a package to use it as an extension of actuator so I just only need actuator dependency and configuration.

How can I do this?

The ultimate goal is to have a dependency named custom-actuator which is just the actuator but with a different default configuration so I can use it in different projects.

Comment: May be create your own spring boot starter?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar yes I can totally create a starter pack still the problem is that pack will only contain dependencies and configuration files. What I am missing, in case of creating a starter, is why do I need any bean at all, and how to code the autoconfiguration bean of the starter to just apply those properties.